# jQuery Notification Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications

I'm trying to install [Noty](http://needim.github.com/noty/) (a jQuery Notification plugin) on a checkout page (FoxyCart template). I installed the following code in the  section of my checkout template:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lavajavamaui.com/js/noty/jquery.noty.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lavajavamaui.com/js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lavajavamaui.com/js/noty/layouts/topLeft.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lavajavamaui.com/js/noty/layouts/topRight.js"></script>
<!-- You can add more layouts if you want -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lavajavamaui.com/js/noty/themes/default.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
</script>
```

If I understand correctly, this is all that needs to be done to get it to display properly. For some reason, the notification is not popping up. Is there something wrong with this line?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
</script>
```

Here is [the page](https://lavajavamaui.foxycart.com/checkout.php?fcsid=pmsf8a8nqsil5bidba5pjdll02) that should have Noty installed.

Comment: Nope, that line is correct.

Comment: lots of errors in that page.. and multiple jquery versions.. you need to fix these first.

Comment: I only have control over that one jquery.min.js (1.7) file. Everything else is from the hosted payment provider. Removed my jQuery include line, still not showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reproducing a bug in the documentation. The line

```
var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

if run in a global context, redefines `noty`, replacing the function `noty` with the result of the `noty` function. In theory this first call should work but any subsequent calls to `noty` will fail because they are trying to call an object as a function. I'm not sure why the first one fails, but it is possible it is related. Try changing the name of the object you are assigning the result to:

```
var notyObj = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

That might fix it.

If you don't need to manipulate the notification after you create it you should also be able to just call it without assigning the result to a variable:

```
noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
```

**Update**

If you execute that statement inside a non-global context (such as jQuery's `ready` event) it will not work because of [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting). Hoisting takes any `var` statement and moves it to the top of the statement. The statement:

```
    (function () {
        var noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
    }());
```

Is turned into:

```
    (function () {
        var noty; // inside this function noty now refers
                  // to a local variable set to "undefined"

        // JavaScript looks for local variables before it looks at globals,
        // so it will use the new local "noty" when it tries to execute the
        // right side of this line. This will fail because you
        // can't invoke undefined
        noty = noty({text: 'noty - a jquery notification library!'});
    }());
```

Comment: You could also wrap the call in a `$(document).ready()` which would move the variable inside the anonymous function (which is what the author does in `js/script.js`).

Comment: @pete That actually wouldn't work due to variable hoisting, I'm going to expand my answer to cover that.

Comment: Variable hoisting has nothing to do with it. I'm talking about putting the `var notyObj = ` statement *in* the anonymous function for `$(document).ready()`. By doing that, the `notyObj` variable is declared (and scoped to) the anonymous function, so that it is not declared on a global scope.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant moving `var noty = noty()` into `ready`. Using a different variable name would still work in a local context just as it would in the global context. I agree, it is always best to keep from cluttering up the global scope. @pete